# Tried to convert Activity to fragment

Tags: java, php, android, android-fragments

I have tried to create a program from one of the tutorials on the website. This program to upload files to PHP server, and the application is works.

My project name is **Upload File To Server**
It have 1 Main Activity and 1 File Path.

This is code for main layout:

```
<RelativeLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:background="@color/colorAccent"
tools:context="me.pratamax.uploadfiletoserver.MainActivity">

<TextView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:textSize="18sp"
    android:id="@+id/tvHeading"
    android:text="Touch the icon below to upload file to server"
    android:textColor="#fff"
    android:textStyle="bold"/>
<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/ivAttachment"
    android:layout_width="100dp"
    android:layout_height="100dp"
    android:src="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"/>

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/tv_file_name"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textColor="#fff"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:layout_below="@+id/ivAttachment"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"/>

<Button
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/b_upload"
    android:text="Upload"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    android:textSize="20sp"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:textColor="#fff"
    android:background="#039be5"/>
</RelativeLayout>
```

And for java Main activity code:

```
package me.pratamax.uploadfiletoserver;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;
import java.io.DataOutputStream;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
import java.net.MalformedURLException;
import java.net.URL;
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener{

private static final int PICK_FILE_REQUEST = 1;
private static final String TAG = MainActivity.class.getSimpleName();
private String selectedFilePath;
private String SERVER_URL = "http://192.168.0.29/aji/AndroidFileUpload/UploadToServer.php";
ImageView ivAttachment;
Button bUpload;
TextView tvFileName;
ProgressDialog dialog;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    ivAttachment = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.ivAttachment);
    bUpload = (Button) findViewById(R.id.b_upload);
    tvFileName = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tv_file_name);
    ivAttachment.setOnClickListener(this);
    bUpload.setOnClickListener(this);
}

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    if(v== ivAttachment){

        //on attachment icon click
        showFileChooser();
    }
    if(v== bUpload){

        //on upload button Click
        if(selectedFilePath != null){
            dialog = ProgressDialog.show(MainActivity.this,"","Uploading File...",true);

            new Thread(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    //creating new thread to handle Http Operations
                    uploadFile(selectedFilePath);
                }
            }).start();
        }else{
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,"Please choose a File First",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }

    }
}

private void showFileChooser() {
    Intent intent = new Intent();
    //sets the select file to all types of files
    intent.setType("file/*");
    //allows to select data and return it
    intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
    //starts new activity to select file and return data
    startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(intent,"Choose File to Upload.."),PICK_FILE_REQUEST);
}

@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    if(resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK){
        if(requestCode == PICK_FILE_REQUEST){
            if(data == null){
                //no data present
                return;
            }


            Uri selectedFileUri = data.getData();
            selectedFilePath = FilePath.getPath(this,selectedFileUri);
            Log.i(TAG,"Selected File Path:" + selectedFilePath);

            if(selectedFilePath != null && !selectedFilePath.equals("")){
                tvFileName.setText(selectedFilePath);
            }else{
                Toast.makeText(this,"Cannot upload file to server",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        }
    }
}

//android upload file to server
public int uploadFile(final String selectedFilePath){

    int serverResponseCode = 0;

    HttpURLConnection connection;
    DataOutputStream dataOutputStream;
    String lineEnd = "\r\n";
    String twoHyphens = "--";
    String boundary = "*****";


    int bytesRead,bytesAvailable,bufferSize;
    byte[] buffer;
    int maxBufferSize = 1 * 1024 * 1024;
    File selectedFile = new File(selectedFilePath);


    String[] parts = selectedFilePath.split("/");
    final String fileName = parts[parts.length-1];

    if (!selectedFile.isFile()){
        dialog.dismiss();

        runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                tvFileName.setText("Source File Doesn't Exist: " + selectedFilePath);
            }
        });
        return 0;
    }else{
        try{
            FileInputStream fileInputStream = new FileInputStream(selectedFile);
            URL url = new URL(SERVER_URL);
            connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            connection.setDoInput(true);//Allow Inputs
            connection.setDoOutput(true);//Allow Outputs
            connection.setUseCaches(false);//Don't use a cached Copy
            connection.setRequestMethod("POST");
            connection.setRequestProperty("Connection", "Keep-Alive");
            connection.setRequestProperty("ENCTYPE", "multipart/form-data");
            connection.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "multipart/form-data;boundary=" + boundary);
            connection.setRequestProperty("uploaded_file",selectedFilePath);

            //creating new dataoutputstream
            dataOutputStream = new DataOutputStream(connection.getOutputStream());

            //writing bytes to data outputstream
            dataOutputStream.writeBytes(twoHyphens + boundary + lineEnd);
            dataOutputStream.writeBytes("Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"uploaded_file\";filename=\""
                    + selectedFilePath + "\"" + lineEnd);

            dataOutputStream.writeBytes(lineEnd);

            //returns no. of bytes present in fileInputStream
            bytesAvailable = fileInputStream.available();
            //selecting the buffer size as minimum of available bytes or 1 MB
            bufferSize = Math.min(bytesAvailable,maxBufferSize);
            //setting the buffer as byte array of size of bufferSize
            buffer = new byte[bufferSize];

            //reads bytes from FileInputStream(from 0th index of buffer to buffersize)
            bytesRead = fileInputStream.read(buffer,0,bufferSize);

            //loop repeats till bytesRead = -1, i.e., no bytes are left to read
            while (bytesRead > 0){
                //write the bytes read from inputstream
                dataOutputStream.write(buffer,0,bufferSize);
                bytesAvailable = fileInputStream.available();
                bufferSize = Math.min(bytesAvailable,maxBufferSize);
                bytesRead = fileInputStream.read(buffer,0,bufferSize);
            }

            dataOutputStream.writeBytes(lineEnd);
            dataOutputStream.writeBytes(twoHyphens + boundary + twoHyphens + lineEnd);

            serverResponseCode = connection.getResponseCode();
            String serverResponseMessage = connection.getResponseMessage();

            Log.i(TAG, "Server Response is: " + serverResponseMessage + ": " + serverResponseCode);

            //response code of 200 indicates the server status OK
            if(serverResponseCode == 200){
                runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        tvFileName.setText("File Upload completed.\n\n You can see the uploaded file here: \n\n" + "http://coderefer.com/extras/uploads/"+ fileName);
                    }
                });
            }

            //closing the input and output streams
            fileInputStream.close();
            dataOutputStream.flush();
            dataOutputStream.close();



        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,"File Not Found",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            });
        } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "URL error!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Cannot Read/Write File!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
        dialog.dismiss();
        return serverResponseCode;
    }
}
}
```

And for file path code:

```
package me.pratamax.uploadfiletoserver;

/**
 * Created by ditaa on 30/08/2016.
 */
import android.annotation.TargetApi;
import android.content.ContentUris;
import android.content.Context;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Build;
import android.os.Environment;
import android.provider.DocumentsContract;
import android.provider.MediaStore;

public class FilePath {

    /**
     * Method for return file path of Gallery image/ Document / Video / Audio
     *
     * @param context
     * @param uri
     * @return path of the selected image file from gallery
     */
    @TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT)
    public static String getPath(final Context context, final Uri uri) {

        // check here to KITKAT or new version
        final boolean isKitKat = Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT;

        // DocumentProvider
        if (isKitKat && DocumentsContract.isDocumentUri(context, uri)) {

            // ExternalStorageProvider
            if (isExternalStorageDocument(uri)) {
                final String docId = DocumentsContract.getDocumentId(uri);
                final String[] split = docId.split(":");
                final String type = split[0];

                if ("primary".equalsIgnoreCase(type)) {
                    return Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/"
                            + split[1];
                }
            }
            // DownloadsProvider
            else if (isDownloadsDocument(uri)) {

                final String id = DocumentsContract.getDocumentId(uri);
                final Uri contentUri = ContentUris.withAppendedId(
                        Uri.parse("content://downloads/public_downloads"),
                        Long.valueOf(id));

                return getDataColumn(context, contentUri, null, null);
            }
            // MediaProvider
            else if (isMediaDocument(uri)) {
                final String docId = DocumentsContract.getDocumentId(uri);
                final String[] split = docId.split(":");
                final String type = split[0];

                Uri contentUri = null;
                if ("image".equals(type)) {
                    contentUri = MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI;
                } else if ("video".equals(type)) {
                    contentUri = MediaStore.Video.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI;
                } else if ("audio".equals(type)) {
                    contentUri = MediaStore.Audio.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI;
                }

                final String selection = "_id=?";
                final String[] selectionArgs = new String[] { split[1] };

                return getDataColumn(context, contentUri, selection,
                        selectionArgs);
            }
        }
        // MediaStore (and general)
        else if ("content".equalsIgnoreCase(uri.getScheme())) {

            // Return the remote address
            if (isGooglePhotosUri(uri))
                return uri.getLastPathSegment();

            return getDataColumn(context, uri, null, null);
        }
        // File
        else if ("file".equalsIgnoreCase(uri.getScheme())) {
            return uri.getPath();
        }

        return null;
    }

    /**
     * Get the value of the data column for this Uri. This is useful for
     * MediaStore Uris, and other file-based ContentProviders.
     *
     * @param context
     *            The context.
     * @param uri
     *            The Uri to query.
     * @param selection
     *            (Optional) Filter used in the query.
     * @param selectionArgs
     *            (Optional) Selection arguments used in the query.
     * @return The value of the _data column, which is typically a file path.
     */
    public static String getDataColumn(Context context, Uri uri,
                                       String selection, String[] selectionArgs) {

        Cursor cursor = null;
        final String column = "_data";
        final String[] projection = { column };

        try {
            cursor = context.getContentResolver().query(uri, projection,
                    selection, selectionArgs, null);
            if (cursor != null && cursor.moveToFirst()) {
                final int index = cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(column);
                return cursor.getString(index);
            }
        } finally {
            if (cursor != null)
                cursor.close();
        }
        return null;
    }

    /**
     * @param uri
     *            The Uri to check.
     * @return Whether the Uri authority is ExternalStorageProvider.
     */
    public static boolean isExternalStorageDocument(Uri uri) {
        return "com.android.externalstorage.documents".equals(uri
                .getAuthority());
    }

    /**
     * @param uri
     *            The Uri to check.
     * @return Whether the Uri authority is DownloadsProvider.
     */
    public static boolean isDownloadsDocument(Uri uri) {
        return "com.android.providers.downloads.documents".equals(uri
                .getAuthority());
    }

    /**
     * @param uri
     *            The Uri to check.
     * @return Whether the Uri authority is MediaProvider.
     */
    public static boolean isMediaDocument(Uri uri) {
        return "com.android.providers.media.documents".equals(uri
                .getAuthority());
    }

    /**
     * @param uri
     *            The Uri to check.
     * @return Whether the Uri authority is Google Photos.
     */
    public static boolean isGooglePhotosUri(Uri uri) {
        return "com.google.android.apps.photos.content".equals(uri
                .getAuthority());
    }
}
```

And some PHP code on my web server. and it's work.

After that, I want to make new project for Upload and Download with Tabs. so I must change it into fragment.

It's have Main Activity, Fragment Download, Fragment Upload, and File Path.

Here is for main layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar">

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
            app:titleTextColor="@color/colorBlack"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways"
            app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light" />

        <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
            android:id="@+id/tabs"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            app:tabMode="fixed"
            app:tabGravity="fill"
            android:background="@color/colorGreenDark"
            app:tabIndicatorColor="@color/colorGray"
            app:tabIndicatorHeight="6dp"/>
    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
        android:id="@+id/viewpager"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"  />
</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Here is for main activity java:

```
package me.pratamax.uploaddownload;

import android.support.design.widget.TabLayout;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentPagerAdapter;
import android.support.v4.view.ViewPager;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private Toolbar toolbar;
    private TabLayout tabLayout;
    private ViewPager viewPager;
    private int[] tabIcons = {
            R.drawable.ic_unarchive_black_24dp,
            R.drawable.ic_archive_black_24dp
    };

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
//        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);  // Kode untuk kasih tombol back

        viewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.viewpager);
        setupViewPager(viewPager);

        tabLayout = (TabLayout) findViewById(R.id.tabs);
        tabLayout.setupWithViewPager(viewPager);
        setupTabIcons();
    }

    private void setupTabIcons() {
        tabLayout.getTabAt(0).setIcon(tabIcons[0]);
        tabLayout.getTabAt(1).setIcon(tabIcons[1]);
    }

    private void setupViewPager(ViewPager viewPager) {
        ViewPagerAdapter adapter = new ViewPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());
        adapter.addFrag(new UploadFragment(), "Upload");
        adapter.addFrag(new DownloadFragment(), "Download");
        viewPager.setAdapter(adapter);
    }

    class ViewPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {
        private final List<Fragment> mFragmentList = new ArrayList<>();
        private final List<String> mFragmentTitleList = new ArrayList<>();

        public ViewPagerAdapter(FragmentManager manager) {
            super(manager);
        }

        @Override
        public Fragment getItem(int position) {
            return mFragmentList.get(position);
        }

        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            return mFragmentList.size();
        }

        public void addFrag(Fragment fragment, String title) {
            mFragmentList.add(fragment);
            mFragmentTitleList.add(title);
        }

        @Override
        public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
            return mFragmentTitleList.get(position);
        }
    }
}
```

I use FilePath.java, UploadFragment.java, and fragment_upload.xml from last project.

But I don't know how to make it work and convert it's activity to fragment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am giving the implementation part of Upload fragment class. Use in the same fashion to achieve the Download fragment class. Your ViewPager consists of two fragments one is upload and other is download. So implement those two classes by extending the Fragment class and override the onCreateView method. So what ever you perform in onCreate in the activity, follow the same and get references from the upload_fragment.xml .

The layout code for upload_fragment is same as your main layout file.

UploadFragment class.

```
public class UploadFragment extends Fragment implements View.OnClickListener{
private static final int PICK_FILE_REQUEST = 1;
private static final String TAG = MainActivity.class.getSimpleName();
private String selectedFilePath;
private String SERVER_URL = "http://192.168.0.29/aji/AndroidFileUpload/UploadToServer.php";
ImageView ivAttachment;
Button bUpload;
TextView tvFileName;
ProgressDialog dialog;
@Nullable
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View rootView;
    rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.upload_frament,container,false);
    ivAttachment = (ImageView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.ivAttachment);
    bUpload = (Button) rootView.findViewById(R.id.b_upload);
    tvFileName = (TextView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.tv_file_name);
    ivAttachment.setOnClickListener(this);
    bUpload.setOnClickListener(this);
    return rootView;
}

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    if(v== ivAttachment){

        //on attachment icon click
        showFileChooser();
    }
    if(v== bUpload){

        //on upload button Click
        if(selectedFilePath != null){
            dialog = ProgressDialog.show(getActivity(),"","Uploading File...",true);

            new Thread(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    //creating new thread to handle Http Operations
                    uploadFile(selectedFilePath);
                }
            }).start();
        }else{
            Toast.makeText(getActivity(),"Please choose a File First",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }

    }
}

private void showFileChooser() {
    Intent intent = new Intent();
    //sets the select file to all types of files
    intent.setType("file/*");
    //allows to select data and return it
    intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
    //starts new activity to select file and return data
    startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(intent,"Choose File to Upload.."),PICK_FILE_REQUEST);
}

//android upload file to server
public int uploadFile(final String selectedFilePath){

    int serverResponseCode = 0;

    HttpURLConnection connection;
    DataOutputStream dataOutputStream;
    String lineEnd = "\r\n";
    String twoHyphens = "--";
    String boundary = "*****";


    int bytesRead,bytesAvailable,bufferSize;
    byte[] buffer;
    int maxBufferSize = 1 * 1024 * 1024;
    File selectedFile = new File(selectedFilePath);


    String[] parts = selectedFilePath.split("/");
    final String fileName = parts[parts.length-1];

    if (!selectedFile.isFile()){
        dialog.dismiss();

        getActivity().runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                tvFileName.setText("Source File Doesn't Exist: " + selectedFilePath);
            }
        });
        return 0;
    }else{
        try{
            FileInputStream fileInputStream = new FileInputStream(selectedFile);
            URL url = new URL(SERVER_URL);
            connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            connection.setDoInput(true);//Allow Inputs
            connection.setDoOutput(true);//Allow Outputs
            connection.setUseCaches(false);//Don't use a cached Copy
            connection.setRequestMethod("POST");
            connection.setRequestProperty("Connection", "Keep-Alive");
            connection.setRequestProperty("ENCTYPE", "multipart/form-data");
            connection.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "multipart/form-data;boundary=" + boundary);
            connection.setRequestProperty("uploaded_file",selectedFilePath);

            //creating new dataoutputstream
            dataOutputStream = new DataOutputStream(connection.getOutputStream());

            //writing bytes to data outputstream
            dataOutputStream.writeBytes(twoHyphens + boundary + lineEnd);
            dataOutputStream.writeBytes("Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"uploaded_file\";filename=\""
                    + selectedFilePath + "\"" + lineEnd);

            dataOutputStream.writeBytes(lineEnd);

            //returns no. of bytes present in fileInputStream
            bytesAvailable = fileInputStream.available();
            //selecting the buffer size as minimum of available bytes or 1 MB
            bufferSize = Math.min(bytesAvailable,maxBufferSize);
            //setting the buffer as byte array of size of bufferSize
            buffer = new byte[bufferSize];

            //reads bytes from FileInputStream(from 0th index of buffer to buffersize)
            bytesRead = fileInputStream.read(buffer,0,bufferSize);

            //loop repeats till bytesRead = -1, i.e., no bytes are left to read
            while (bytesRead > 0){
                //write the bytes read from inputstream
                dataOutputStream.write(buffer,0,bufferSize);
                bytesAvailable = fileInputStream.available();
                bufferSize = Math.min(bytesAvailable,maxBufferSize);
                bytesRead = fileInputStream.read(buffer,0,bufferSize);
            }

            dataOutputStream.writeBytes(lineEnd);
            dataOutputStream.writeBytes(twoHyphens + boundary + twoHyphens + lineEnd);

            serverResponseCode = connection.getResponseCode();
            String serverResponseMessage = connection.getResponseMessage();

            Log.i(TAG, "Server Response is: " + serverResponseMessage + ": " + serverResponseCode);

            //response code of 200 indicates the server status OK
            if(serverResponseCode == 200){
                getActivity().runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        tvFileName.setText("File Upload completed.\n\n You can see the uploaded file here: \n\n" + "http://coderefer.com/extras/uploads/"+ fileName);
                    }
                });
            }

            //closing the input and output streams
            fileInputStream.close();
            dataOutputStream.flush();
            dataOutputStream.close();



        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            getActivity().runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    Toast.makeText(getActivity(),"File Not Found",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            });
        } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "URL error!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Cannot Read/Write File!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
        dialog.dismiss();
        return serverResponseCode;
    }
}

@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    if(resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK){
        if(requestCode == PICK_FILE_REQUEST){
            if(data == null){
                //no data present
                return;
            }


            Uri selectedFileUri = data.getData();
            selectedFilePath = FilePath.getPath(this,selectedFileUri);
            Log.i(TAG,"Selected File Path:" + selectedFilePath);

            if(selectedFilePath != null && !selectedFilePath.equals("")){
                tvFileName.setText(selectedFilePath);
            }else{
                Toast.makeText(getActivity(),"Cannot upload file to server",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

}

Answer (score 1):

I have use the same code in a fragment.only thing you need to do is make the network call inside a async task.

```
 class RetrieveFeedTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Integer> {
    @Override
    protected Integer doInBackground(String... strings) {
        int serverResponseCode = 0;

        HttpURLConnection connection;
        DataOutputStream dataOutputStream;
        String lineEnd = "\r\n";
        String twoHyphens = "--";
        String boundary = "*****";


        int bytesRead,bytesAvailable,bufferSize;
        byte[] buffer;
        int maxBufferSize = 1 * 1024 * 1024;
        File selectedFile = new File(strings[0]);


        String[] parts = strings[0].split("/");
        final String fileName = parts[parts.length-1];


        try{
            FileInputStream fileInputStream = new FileInputStream(selectedFile);
            URL url = new URL("url");
            connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            connection.setDoInput(true);//Allow Inputs
            connection.setDoOutput(true);//Allow Outputs
            connection.setUseCaches(false);//Don't use a cached Copy
            connection.setRequestMethod("POST");
            connection.setRequestProperty("Connection", "Keep-Alive");
            connection.setRequestProperty("ENCTYPE", "multipart/form-data");
            connection.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "multipart/form-data;boundary=" + boundary);
            connection.setRequestProperty("uploaded_file",strings[0]);

            //creating new dataoutputstream
            dataOutputStream = new DataOutputStream(connection.getOutputStream());

            //writing bytes to data outputstream
            dataOutputStream.writeBytes(twoHyphens + boundary + lineEnd);
            dataOutputStream.writeBytes("Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"uploaded_file\";filename=\""
                    + strings[0] + "\"" + lineEnd);

            dataOutputStream.writeBytes(lineEnd);

            //returns no. of bytes present in fileInputStream
            bytesAvailable = fileInputStream.available();
            //selecting the buffer size as minimum of available bytes or 1 MB
            bufferSize = Math.min(bytesAvailable,maxBufferSize);
            //setting the buffer as byte array of size of bufferSize
            buffer = new byte[bufferSize];

            //reads bytes from FileInputStream(from 0th index of buffer to buffersize)
            bytesRead = fileInputStream.read(buffer,0,bufferSize);

            //loop repeats till bytesRead = -1, i.e., no bytes are left to read
            while (bytesRead > 0){
                //write the bytes read from inputstream
                dataOutputStream.write(buffer,0,bufferSize);
                bytesAvailable = fileInputStream.available();
                bufferSize = Math.min(bytesAvailable,maxBufferSize);
                bytesRead = fileInputStream.read(buffer,0,bufferSize);
            }

            dataOutputStream.writeBytes(lineEnd);
            dataOutputStream.writeBytes(twoHyphens + boundary + twoHyphens + lineEnd);

            serverResponseCode = connection.getResponseCode();
            String serverResponseMessage = connection.getResponseMessage();

            Log.i(TAG, "Server Response is: " + serverResponseMessage + ": " + serverResponseCode);

            //response code of 200 indicates the server status OK
            if(serverResponseCode == 200){
                getActivity().runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        // tvFileName.setText("File Upload completed.\n\n You can see the uploaded file here: \n\n" + "http://coderefer.com/extras/uploads/"+ fileName);
                    }
                });
            }

            //closing the input and output streams
            fileInputStream.close();
            dataOutputStream.flush();
            dataOutputStream.close();



        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            getActivity().runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    Toast.makeText(getActivity(),"File Not Found",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            });
        } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "URL error!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Cannot Read/Write File!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
        //dialog.dismiss();
        return serverResponseCode;


    }

}
```